# How to use the css scale "rem" in ReactJS by setting <html> font-size

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have an HTML file with its CSS and I suppose to take it as a component in my React project. But all the font sizes are scaled in **rem**. What is the easiest way to set font-size of root html to 10px, **but only for that component.** And I'm using **Stateless Components**.

```
 html {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: There is only _one_ root element in a document, so how should that be possible at all? _Only_ way I could see this working, is if you put your component into an iframe - which has its own root element, that could get its own individual font size set. But that is probably not an actually useable solution in practice …

Comment: @CBroe thank you. If it is not ideal, I think it's better if I change the rem units to pixels because.

Comment: Maybe use em instead? I am currently asking a somewhat similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70095058/different-media-queries-for-html-for-different-routes-in-react